# Performance difference if I UNION first, then put WHERE on unioned result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In Microsoft SQL, is there any difference in performance between this:

```
SELECT columns FROM table1 WHERE cond
UNION
SELECT columns FROM table2 WHERE cond
```

and this:

```
SELECT columns FROM
(
SELECT columns FROM table1
UNION
SELECT columns FROM table2
) WHERE cond
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former is preferrable because if index(es) exist on any column referenced in the WHERE clause (barring being wrapped in function calls), the index(es) can be used.

The latter is a derived table, so index use is out of the question.

Comment: In addition, use "UNION ALL" if there is no chance of duplicate rows from between the two tables.